# Does QCoh commute with colimits?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, infinity-categories, kan-extension

If $S$ is a scheme, denote by $QCoh(S)$ the $\infty$-derived category of quasi-coherent sheaves on $S$. If $X$ is a prestack, Gaitsgory and Rozenbluym define in their book $QCoh(X)$ as a right Kan extension: $QCoh(X)=\operatorname{holim}_{S\to X} QCoh(S)$ (the transition maps are given by derived pullback).

Assume that $X=\operatorname{hocolim}_{i\in I}X_i$, where $I:i\mapsto X_i$ is a diagram of prestacks. Then I think it should be true that $QCoh(X)=\operatorname{holim}_{i\in I} QCoh(X_i)$. Could you explain this in detail? While building the theory of QCoh, I think this is one of the first steps; if so please don't apply more sophisticated results.

I think I must show that $\operatorname{holim}_{i\in I}\operatorname{holim}_{S\to X_i} = \operatorname{holim}_{S\to X}$. Maybe a cofinality argument is required?

(Of course, one switches holim and hocolim because the functor is contravariant...)

Comment: If $F : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ is a functor, then its left Kan extension along the Yoneda embedding $\mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{C})$ is colimit preserving (provided that it exists), see for instance higher topos theory lemma 5.1.5.5. The assertion that $\operatorname{QCoh}$ preserves colimits follows from this by letting $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of affine schemes, and $\mathcal{D}$ be the opposite of the category of large categories.